# WCF Performance degradation and messages failing

Tags: wcf, performance, wcf-binding, appfabric

We are currently in the process of setting up servers for our Production move.

In our current setup, we have kept the Web and the App servers on separate boxes.
But, in one of our load test scenario, a performance test with concurrent users did not show optimal results.

Our WCF configuration is currently left at 'out-of-the-box' setup values.

how to change/adjust the WCF configuration for optimal performance.We are trying to Test with 200 users and its hosted in appfabric.
To add we are using NetTcpBinding.
May be if we can add an optimal settings it will also help

Comment: Have your actually attempted to find the bottleneck. Adding some simple logging and diagnostics would reveal a large amount about what is going on and where.

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration play imortant role in performance.

1. ServiceThrottling behavior
2. NetTcpBinding.ListenBacklog and NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections
3. Database query optimazation.

You can refer these articles.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(v=bts.10).aspx
2. http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/load-balancing-and-scaling-your-wcf-services-122258
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/11/why-does-wcf-become-slow-after-being-idle-for-15-seconds.aspx
4. http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/concurrency-and-throttling-configurations-for-wcf-services